# Are there any signs for an end-user of cellular calls being routed through a Stingray device?

Tags: man-in-the-middle, mobile, wireless, cellular

The Stingray is a small device that mimics cellular towers. From the user's endpoint side, is there any way to detect you are being routed through a rogue cellular tower?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Android Devices you can monitor all cellular Towers you are connected to with AIMSICD (https://github.com/CellularPrivacy/Android-IMSI-Catcher-Detector/wiki) so if you connect to an unknown cellular Tower (an attacker) in an area where it already knows the "good" cellular towers the device normaly connects to it warns you.

Quoting the github Page:

> AIMSICD attempts to detect IMSI-Catchers through detection methods such as these:
>
> - Check Tower Information Consistency
> - Check LAC/Cell ID Consistency
> - Check Neighboring Cell Info
> - Prevent silent app installations
> - Monitor Signal Strength
> - Detect silent SMS
> - Detect FemtoCells